# How to schedule a Jenkins job each 15 minutes between 2:45 AM and 4:00 AM on 20th August?

Tags: java, jenkins

I wanted to schedule a Jenkins job each 15 minutes between 2:45 AM and 4:00 AM on 20th August after a code deployment happens. How can i do that ?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

You would need the following two lines :

```
45 02 20 08 *
*/15 03-04 20 08 *
```

First Line  : At 02:45 on day-of-month 20 in August

Second Line : At every 15th minute past every hour from 3 through 4 on day-of-month 20 in August